# Reading transfer function values from Bode plot

Tags: control-system, bode-plot

I am trying to get back into control systems and at the moment I am stuck on how to extract the damping ratio and gain from the Bode plot I generated.

[image]

Firstly the gain. As far as I can remember the gain is the value at f = 0, so 0 dB in my case. Is this correct?

The damping ratio can be calculated from the peak at the resonance frequency somehow, but I am unable to find a fitting formula here. So how can one find/calculate this value from the Bode plot?

Comment: Your circuit is slightly non-standard because of the 5 milli ohm resistor in series with the 20 uF hence, it's likely that if you want an exact answer, you'll need to derive it. If that 5 milli ohm were zero ohm, the damping ratio would be 0.0246

Comment: @Andyaka Thanks for the comment! How did you derive the damping ratio for the zero ohm Case?

Comment: I made a web-calculator that does that

Comment: Can you please share the analytic equation behind that one for the damping ratio?

Comment: Will this form an acceptable answer because it's not a simple derivation to present.

Comment: Yes, of course!

Comment: My ultimate goal is to model this transfer function and i already have the form and all coefficients except the damping ratio.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A 2nd order low-pass peaking plot with magnitude information can be found on my [website](http://www.stades.co.uk/): -

[image]

If you need more details of how that formula is derived I can add that information. I've added that now - see **derivation #1** lower down.

So, the trick here is reverse engineer the above formula: -

$$P = \dfrac{1}{2\zeta\sqrt{1 - \zeta^2}}$$

And, if you manipulate this into a quadratic solving for \$\zeta^2\$ you get: -

$$\zeta^2 = \dfrac{1\pm\sqrt{1-\frac{1}{P^2}}}{2}$$

So, if the peak is 20 times higher than the DC value (a peak gain of about 26 dB) you get this: -

$$\zeta^2 = \dfrac{1\pm\sqrt{0.9975}}{2}$$

Clearly the wrong answer is found when the numerator terms are added. If subtracted: -

$$\zeta^2 = 0.00062539111 $$

And \$\zeta =\$ 0.025.

---

**Added derivation #1**

---

[image]

---

**Added web calculator**

---

This is a calculator (also from my website) that shows the actual damping ratio (\$\zeta\$). It's a simple case of adding the two resistors in the original circuit into one lump value of 0.0025 Ω: -

[image]

You can find the calculator [here](http://www.stades.co.uk/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

> Your circuit is too complicated to solve analytically. I provided some guidelines and analyzed your specific circuit at the bottom of my answer.

Well, let's analyze this circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ftYZMv.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The transfer function is given by:

$$\mathscr{H}\left(\text{s}\right):=\frac{\text{V}_\text{o}\left(\text{s}\right)}{\text{V}_\text{i}\left(\text{s}\right)}=\frac{\displaystyle\text{R}_2+\frac{1}{\displaystyle\text{sC}}}{\text{R}_1+\text{sL}+\text{R}_2+\frac{1}{\text{sC}}}=\frac{1+\text{CR}_2\text{s}}{\text{CL}\text{s}^2+\text{C}\left(\text{R}_1+\text{R}_2\right)\text{s}+1}\tag1$$

Now, we want to solve for the value that \$\displaystyle\left|\space\underline{\mathscr{H}}\left(\text{j}\omega\right)\right|\$ is at a maximum:

$$\frac{\partial\left|\space\underline{\mathscr{H}}\left(\text{j}\hat{\omega}\right)\right|}{\partial\hat{\omega}}=0\space\Longleftrightarrow\space\hat{\omega}=\dots\tag2$$

Solving this gives:

$$\hat{\omega}=\frac{1}{\text{CR}_2}\cdot\sqrt{\frac{\displaystyle\sqrt{\left(\text{L}-\text{CR}_1\text{R}_2\right)\left(\text{L}+\text{CR}_2\left(\text{R}_1+2\text{R}_2\right)\right)}}{\text{L}}-1}\tag3$$

With the condition that \$\text{CR}_1\left(\text{R}_1+2\text{R}_2\right)<2\text{L}\$.

At the maximum we get:

$$\left|\space\underline{\mathscr{H}}\left(\text{j}\hat{\omega}\right)\right|=\dots\tag4$$

So, the cut-off frequency can be solved:

$$\left|\space\underline{\mathscr{H}}\left(\text{j}\omega\right)\right|=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\cdot\left|\space\underline{\mathscr{H}}\left(\text{j}\hat{\omega}\right)\right|\space\Longleftrightarrow\space\omega=\dots\tag5$$

Which gives:

$$\omega_\pm=\dots\tag6$$

So, the bandwidth is given by:

$$\mathcal{B}:=\left|\omega_+-\omega_-\right|=\dots\tag7$$

And the quality factor is given by:

$$\mathcal{Q}:=\frac{\hat{\omega}}{\mathcal{B}}=\dots\tag8$$

---

For your specific circuit we find:

$$\hat{\omega}=1000000 \sqrt{\frac{\sqrt{1210366}}{11}-100}\approx122974.8895\space\text{rad/sec}$$
$$\left|\space\underline{\mathscr{H}}\left(\text{j}\hat{\omega}\right)\right|=\sqrt{\frac{3168 \sqrt{1210366}}{26375}+\frac{3485327}{26375}}\approx16.257$$
$$\omega_\pm=\frac{125000}{33} \sqrt{2 \left(6336 \sqrt{1210366}\pm\sqrt{48590017190881-44166063744 \sqrt{1210366}}-6970127\right)}$$
$$\omega_+\approx126707.9218\space\text{rad/sec}$$
$$\omega_-\approx119124.9685\space\text{rad/sec}$$
$$\mathcal{B}=\frac{250000}{33} \sqrt{6336 \sqrt{1210366}-528 \sqrt{174266351-158400 \sqrt{1210366}}-6970127}\approx7582.95\space\text{rad/sec}$$
$$\mathcal{Q}=12 \sqrt{\frac{11 \left(\sqrt{1210366}-1100\right)}{6336 \sqrt{1210366}-528 \sqrt{\frac{345895201}{158400 \sqrt{1210366}+174266351}}-6970127}}\approx16.2173$$